# Use JavaScript to rename Spotify Web player in Spotify Connect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, spotify

I mostly use the Spotify Web Player to listen to Spotify. Sometimes when I have lots of Web Players open, it gets confusing on Spotify Connect when they all say "Web Player (Chrome)". I was wondering if it was possible to run JavaScript in the console to change the name of the player in Spotify Connect. Also I don't have Spotify Premium so using the Web Player SDK isn't an option.

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear above, I meant changing the title in Spotify Connect
[change from "Web Player (chrome)" that is shown in popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Uam.png)
I was wondering if it would be possible for JavaScript to switch the name from "Web Player (chrome)" to something more useful to indentify

Answer (score 0):

Sadly as of now no, Spotify connect is meant to really be used as a remote, sort of like your TV. The SDK is the only way to make your own player and interact with it.

If you do pay for the subscription then you could make your own player, but that is a lot of work as I am doing that right now. Keep in mind if you do try to make your own player that Widevine is a big issue and the only way to use it is Chrome, Firefox etc. So you can't make your own desktop app. You would need Spotify connect for that.